# SharePoint Online - Current user doesn't have access

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-workflow

We have SharePoint application running in designer 2013 workflow. Currently the user facing the permission issue. But they have required permission to approve the flow.

Thanks in advance.

Need the solution/guidance to fix this